# Screen record using VLC - command line - windows xp

Tags: command-line, vlc

My objective is to start and stop screen record using VLC from command line.

For starting the screen recording, I used the following code:

```
vlc screen://  -I rc --screen-follow-mouse --screen-fps 5    
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=WMV2,vb=1800,scale=1}:std{access=file,mux=asf,dst=output.wmv}
```

And for stopping the record I learned from the VLC forums that I have to use `ncat` for windows and my stop BAT file contents were

```
echo quit | "C:\Users\Jk\Desktop\Downloads\nc111nt\nc.exe" localhost 8088
```

But still the stop doesn't work. I also tried the following, but it makes the recorded video corrupted:

```
taskkill /IM vlc.exe
```

Also tried

vlc ://quit but it wont work as it was not started in one-instance mode.

Answer (score 0):

To stop, just run:

```
vlc vlc://quit
```

Comment: No vlc://quit is not working. Since it will work only in one-instance mode.